# AngularJs create scope from a model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a complex model structure (detailed below) and everytime I want to use the `ng-model` I have to do access the exact property like the following: `user.communications.inGame.selected`.

I would like to be able to be able to scope an area and be able to use the inner `selected` **without all the prefixes** (simply writing `selected`), just like I am able to with `ng-repeat`.

`ng-repeat` won't fit here since every communication has different properties inside it, and I don't wan't to have a gigantic `ng-switch` inside it.

**The data structure**

```
 $scope.user.communications = {
            inGame: {
                name: 'inGame',
                selected: true,
                image: 'assets/img/communication/ingame.png'
            },
            teamspeak: {
                name: 'teamspeak',
                selected: true,
                image: 'assets/img/communication/ts.png',
                serverAddress: '',
                port: '',
                nickname: '',
                password: '',
                channel: '',
                channelPassword: '',
                autoBookmarkAdd: ''
            },
            skype: {
                id: 3,
                name: 'skype',
                selected: true,
                image: 'assets/img/communication/skype.png',
                username: ''
            },
            ventrilo: {
                name: 'ventrilo',
                selected: true,
                image: 'assets/img/communication/ventrilo.png',
                serverName: '',
                port: '',
                serverPassword: '',
                channelName: '',
                channelPassword: ''
            }
        };
```

Comment: Maybe write your own directive?  Something like `ng-with` and then do `ng-with="user.communications.inGame"` Not sure if this would work for you or not as it would mean that template would then need to be in the directive.  Just an idea though.

Comment: I want to get the same effect as ng-repeat just without repeating,
Hoping to find a built-in solution, otherwise I might try implementing one

Comment: I think you will need at least one prefix.

Comment: I can't think of anything already in Angular that has that capabilities, that's why i suggested writing your own directive.  I did find this maybe it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124645/shouldnt-there-be-an-angularjs-ngwith-directive?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

please check below html, you can use it something like this

```
 <div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
   <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">      
     <ul class="unstyled">
       <li ng-repeat="todo in user.communications">
         {{todo.selected}}
      </li>
    </ul>    
 </div>
    </div>
```

and in controller

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
$scope.user={};
$scope.user.communications = {
        inGame: {
            name: 'inGame',
            selected: true,
            image: 'assets/img/communication/ingame.png'
        },
        teamspeak: {
            name: 'teamspeak',
            selected: true,
            image: 'assets/img/communication/ts.png',
            serverAddress: '',
            port: '',
            nickname: '',
            password: '',
            channel: '',
            channelPassword: '',
            autoBookmarkAdd: ''
        },
        skype: {
            id: 3,
            name: 'skype',
            selected: true,
            image: 'assets/img/communication/skype.png',
            username: ''
        },
        ventrilo: {
            name: 'ventrilo',
            selected: true,
            image: 'assets/img/communication/ventrilo.png',
            serverName: '',
            port: '',
            serverPassword: '',
            channelName: '',
            channelPassword: ''
        }
    };
```

}

please refer : http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1505/

Comment: Thanks, but I've already mentioned that ng-repeat won't fit here since every communication has different properties, I want to be able to access other properties as well without using ng-switch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create scopes on the fly while individually selecting each of the items in `$scope.user.communications`, you can simply use `ng-init`. However, it will require at least one prefix

```
    <div ng-model="one" ng-init="one=user.communications.inGame">
        {{ one.selected }}
    </div>
    ...
```