# Set scope to child of current scope within template in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Say I've got a template something like this:

```
<div id="player" ng-show="player.is_visible">
  <p ng-class="player.foo_class">...</p>
  <p ng-class="player.bar_class">...</p>
  <p ng-class="player.baz_class">...</p>
<div>
```

How can I narrow the scope inside #player like this?

```
<div id="player" ng-show="player.is_visible" ng-inner-scope="player">
  <p ng-class="foo_class">...</p>
  <p ng-class="bar_class">...</p>
  <p ng-class="baz_class">...</p>
<div>
```

Comment: `player` is not instance of scope i.e. not successor of `$rootScope`. You cant do this and it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124645/shouldnt-there-be-an-angularjs-ngwith-directive